# Running my file change event listener results in TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: angular, typescript, multipartform-data, angular-reactive-forms, image-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images in angular. Upon running my code on change on the file input element i get the error "Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'." in the  browser console log. My code is as follows:

````
 

       // listing gallery images
    
        onFileChange(event) {
         this.gallery = true;
         if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    
          // clears some arrays
          this.imagePaths = [];
          this.galleryPreview = [];
          const filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
    
          for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            const file = event.target.files[i];
    
            // checks file validity
            if (!this.validateFile(file.name)) {
              this.isValidFormat = false;
              console.log('Selected file format is not supported');
              return false;
            } 
            this.isValidFormat = true;
    
            // Assigns filelist value to form control
            const files = event.target.files;
            this.myForm.patchValue({
              files: files
            });
    
            // handles image previews
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
              const file = event.target.result;
              this.isValidFormat = true;
              this.galleryPreview.push(file);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
          }
          
        }    
        this.gallery = false;
        }
      ```
    Every time i choose images i get the above error. Please point out the errors in my code.
    The form is as follows:
    ```
   

 this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)],
      }),     
     
      files: new FormControl(null, { 
        validators: [Validators.required], 
        asyncValidators: [mimeType]}),      
      tags: new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required] }),
    });
    // subscription on start
````

Comment: You don't have `readAsArrayBuffer` in the snippet. Did you meant `readAsDataURL`?

Comment: no I am getting the error as above.. Even if I omit the image preview code entirely.

Comment: Sorry for wasting you time. I figured it out. It was my async validators returning the error.